# Is it possible to start an Android Service from a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I want to start a `Service` from a `BroadcastReceiver` in Android. Is it possible?
Can anyone please tell me how a `Service` is started in a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Off course possible but what's your problem???

Comment: not only that it's possible, but it's also recommended when this is receiver that registered in the application's manifest

Answer (score 2):

> in android it is possible

Yes.

> Can anyone please tell how Service being started in broadcast receiver?

Call `startService()` on the `Context` passed into your `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`.